# Angularjs server side pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use spring mvc and rest to get large data from database so the application is very slow  I want to load only a subset of records using server side pagination by AngularJS.
Can any one help me to do that or give me good tutorial?

Comment: What do you mean by server side pagination? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can create $resource and a link for rest.The page number you can get from link (GET method) or from object (POST method).If you want I can give you an example.

Comment: What kind of help do you need?